# Quotes Issue when Reading from XML File in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I'm trying to read from XML and store the data in a text file.
My code works very well in reading and storing the data, EXCEPT when the paragraph from the XML file contains double quotes.

For example:

```
    <Agent> "The famous spy" James Bond </Agent>
```

The output will ignore any data with quotes, and the result would be: James Bond

I'm using SAX, and here is part of my code that might have the issue:

```
 public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException 
  { 
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length); 
  }
```

I think I should replace the Quotes before storing the string in my tempVal.

Any ideas???

**HERE is the complete code just in case:**

> public class Entailment {
>
> ```
>   private String Text;
>
>   private String Hypothesis;
>
>   private String ID;
>
>   private String Entailment;
> ```
>
> }

```
//Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    //reset
    tempVal = "";
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pair")) {
        //create a new instance of Entailment
        tempEntailment = new Entailment();
        tempEntailment.setID(attributes.getValue("id"));
        tempEntailment.setEntailment(attributes.getValue("entailment"));
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pair")) {
        //add it to the list
        Entailments.add(tempEntailment);
    }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
        tempEntailment.setText(tempVal);
    }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
        tempEntailment.setHypothesis(tempVal);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    XMLtoTXT spe = new XMLtoTXT();
    spe.runExample();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `characters()` method is being invoked multiple times because the parser is treating the input as several adjacent text nodes.  The way your code is written (which you did not show) your are probably keeping only the last text node.

You need to accumulate the contents of adjacent text nodes yourself.

```
StringBuilder tempVal = null;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    //reset
    tempVal = new StringBuilder();
    ....
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    tempVal.append(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    String textValue = tempVal.toString();
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works perfect in reading the XML file. Except when dealing with quotes. I tested it with many XML files and the results were as expected. The bug shows only when the paragraph in the XML tag contains quotes. Which means the part of my code where I trace the characters from the XML file , I should consider reading the quotes properly.

Comment: Did you verify that `characters()` is not being called twice? Saying "It works for everything except quotes" doesn't prove anything.  The way your updated code looks, if you got two adjacent calls you'd discard the text in the first node and take the second.  In _general_, a `characters()` method MUST be written to allow the parser to call it multiple times in a row with adjacent text nodes.  Yours does not do that.

Comment: XML parsers are allowed to split the text node wherever they like. If you are using an XML parser that chooses to split the text node when it sees double-quotes, then it will behave exactly the way you describe.

Comment: Thanks all, StringBuilder was the solution as I believe String doesn't deal with quotes.

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with it.  When your code received the second of two text nodes in a row (one containing the quoted string and one with the rest) it replaced the first with the second.  My use of StringBuilder allowed it to accumulate both text nodes into one string. This has nothing to do with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough I simulated your situation and my SAX parser works fine. I'm using jdk 1.6.0_20, and this is how I create my parser:

```
  // Obtain a new instance of a SAXParserFactory.
  SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  // Specifies that the parser produced by this code will provide support for XML namespaces.
  factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  // Specifies that the parser produced by this code will validate documents as they are parsed.
  factory.setValidating(true);
  // Creates a new instance of a SAXParser using the currently configured factory parameters.
  saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
```

My XML header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

What about you?

Comment: I tried this method, the same problem. Maybe I'm missing something, here is a link to the XML that I read: http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/infer/data/byformat/rte/RTE2_dev.xml

Comment: Thanks all, StringBuilder was the solution as I believe String doesn't deal with quotes.